# Sending billing details via POST request to an API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to send all the billing details from a purchase (working with woocommerce) to an API via POST request. What's the best way/place to do so? I guess that using some sort of hooks inside my `wp-content/themes/current_theme/functions.php` but I'm not sure at all about it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This seems like a use case for [Webhooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/).

Comment: How could I persist some sort of authorization token using this method?

Comment: Adding a webhook gives you a secret key. The application you're POSTing to would just need to check for that key.

Comment: But I'm talking about the authorization token given by the API, not wordpress nor woocommerce. This requires a login and then a Bearer token to be present in each subsequent request to the API.